# MySQL Enterprise Backup GUI (or a live backup alternative)

Tags: mysql, backup, xtrabackup, percona

I am looking into [MySQL Enterprise backup](http://www.mysql.com/products/enterprise/backup.html) solution. I am interested in a non-blocking mysql backup (live and incremental).

MySQL Enterprise provides this solution (we have the subscription already).  But from what I see it's only a console application (and not the most user friendly one).

I am not interested in making wrapper scripts or GUI for MySQL Enterprise Backup. Can you recommend some thing which eases the operation of live backup.